# MatPlotLib won't install without python 3.5 or above and pip 18 and above, and I don't have root access

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, root

I have been given remote access to a server. And I need to use modules such as pyswarms. However pyswarms attempts to install Matplotlib and Matplotlib 3 requires python 3.5 or higher and/or pip 9 or higher.
On that server there is python 3.4 and pip 8.
I have been installing modules with --user.
I don't have root access so i can't use sudo. I tried updating pip but it installed the same version (8) again.
Any way around this?

Collecting matplotlib>=1.3.1 (from pyswarms)
   Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/89/0c  /653aec68e9cfb775c4fbae8f71011206e5e7fe4d60fcf01ea1a9d3bc957f/matplotlib-3.0.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
Matplotlib 3.0+ does not support Python 2.x, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3, or 3.4.
Beginning with Matplotlib 3.0, Python 3.5 and above is required.

This may be due to an out of date pip.

Make sure you have pip >= 9.0.1.
```

Answer (score 0):

Install packages with constraints:

```
pip install pyswarms 'matplotlib<3.0'
```

That is, install pyswarms (any version) and install matplotlib with version less than 3.0.